# Should i normalize or denormalize my database for reservation system?

Tags: database, database-design, normalization, denormalization

I'm trying to design my database for our Reservation System, but the thing is i got confused whether should i still Normalized my Database or not .

My question is that whether is it really necessary to Normalize Database when it involves Multivalued Data ?

thank you !

Comment: Care to show us an example of your structure? Generally you should normalise where necessary. Without a sample of your project, or your expected output we couldn't possibly comment on what you should do.

Answer (score 1):

The trouble with "denormalization" is that it isn't a plan that tells you what to do.  It's like trying to drive to Los Angeles from Chicago by driving away from New York.  You need an alternative design discipline to avoid haphazard design, unless you have a lot of prior experience.

In general, you will find that normalized schemas result in fewer bottlenecks for transaction processing, while other designs can be more streamlined for analytic processing.  Star schema is one such design.  Reservation systems are generally extremely transaction oriented, so a more normalized design will probably serve you better than a less normalized one. You haven't said what the scale of your reservation system is.

Normalization is just the beginning of a responsive system.  You'll need to pay attention to physical database design and application software design as well.

Very large scale organizations that do reservation processing often have a second database for analytic processing.  This could be called a data mart, or maybe even a data warehouse.  This database isn't deeply normalized, but instead uses some other design principle, such as star schema.  Periodically, a process extracts data from the reservation system, transforms it to the data mart form, and loads it into the data mart.  Your scale may be too small for such a solution.